# How to sanitize username that would be in urls

Tags: python, regex

What is a good regex filter for usernames?  `[A-Za-z0-9 ]` okay, or is that too inflexible?  What other things should I look for?  (Trimming whitespaces?)

Comment: It would also be on display, so I don't want to make it super easy to fake being another user (say, with a space at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fine for a un, but you might want to let them use `-`, `_`, `%`, `@` and `.`. (Basically, `[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]`). Many people will like using their email for a username and that covers well over 99% of them. In low security situations, I say let'em.

Comment: @machine Originally I had suggested `\w` and then I deleted that for some reason. I've added that back in.

Answer (score 3):

Just [encode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) the username when you are using it in a URL.

Comment: ... and allow anything. I like the way Drupal allows any character in the username. I don't like the way Django doesn't allow spaces, for no good reason that I can think of (though I confess I haven't actually looked).

Answer (score 1):

Your comment to your original answer is the real "problem" here. Encoding the username with base64 or whatever when transfering them is simple, but if you allow your users to chose arbitrary unicode usernames they can easily imitate others.

The basic idea is, that unicode has many characters which while looking identically are encoded differently. See here for a longer description of [homograph attacks](http://www.securityninja.co.uk/hacking/what-are-homograph-attacks/). No idea if there's any library out there that handles this sensibly, but if you want a simple regex solution there, you really should stick to some limited character range